# How to keep the hover state with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Currently it is possible for me to manually trigger hover event of highcharts like below code to show tooltip and highlight the series.

```
chart.series[0].points[2].onMouseOver()
```

However the state can be easily changed after moving the mouse.Is there a way for me to keep the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your tooltip visible when mouse pointer is out you need to disabled **tooltip.hide** functionality.

```
Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype.hide = function() {};
```

and highligt point again after mouse out:

```
    events: {
      mouseOut() {
        let series = this;

        series.points[2].onMouseOver();
      }
    }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xjzc25aL/

Answer (score 0):

For those who are simply trying to make the tooltip visible for a longer time, there is the `hideDelay` property.

For example, to make it last 5 seconds you can write

```
chart.tooltip.options.hideDelay = 5000;
```